# How to add timestamp with custom text using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-xp, autohotkey

From a keyboard shortcut I want to add this text

```
Custom text - 31/12/09 - 10:00:15(GMT)
```

**Time, date and Time zone** should be taken from System in same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^!v::     
FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,, dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm:ss  
SendRaw Jitendra - %CurrentDateTime%(GMT)  
Return
```

The proof: Jitendra - 09/01/2010 - 05:41:15(GMT)

**edit:**
Alright, try this:

```
^!v::
FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,, dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm:ss
time:=A_Now 
EnvSub, time, A_NowUTC, Hours
SendRaw Jitendra - %CurrentDateTime%(GMT
if time>0
sendraw +%time%
if time<0
sendraw %time%
sendraw )
Return
```

It's by no means perfect (and I actually haven't tested it, too much effort to change timezones), but it's conceptually sound, and should output things like GMT+1, or GMT-2, or something.

Comment: is timezone dynamic?

Comment: based on system time

Comment: Nope, but I'm working on it :)

Comment: Right, I don't believe AHK can get what timezone you are, but if you use `A_NowUTC` instead of the blank argument after `CurrentDateTime`, you can be sure it's GMT. Best I've got, sorry :(

Comment: @BlueNovember - I mean system and timezone can be changed

Comment: @Phoshi - But system time and date is according to time zone - http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/domain/timezone.jpg

Comment: Yes, and Autohotkey will grab those fine, but I simply cannot find a way to grab **which** timezone it is. You could probably work out GMT+/-X hours using both `A_Now`, and `A_NowUTC`, but is it necessary?

Comment: Ok, it wasn't very difficult - hopefully this should work for you?

Comment: @Phoshi - it's not necessary for me but i want to share this script with my some friends who are in different States

Comment: @Phoshi - it giving this output <code>0Jitendra - 09/01/2010 - 11:32:28(GMT)</code>

Comment: @Phoshi - and is it possible to show timezone like this http://www.microsoft.com/library/media/1033/windowsxp/images/using/setup/tips/67446-change-time-zone.gif i mean like this (GMT+05:30)

Comment: Alright, `A_Now` and `A_NowUTC` are providing exactly the same result when I change my timezone. Damn.

Comment: Right, fixed! Apparently one can't format before performing the maths or things break horribly. Oh well.

Comment: it's almost right <code>Jitendra - 09/01/2010 - 11:41:59(GMT+5)</code> but GMT+5 has 4 variants.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas, but hopefully somebody else can solve your problem :)

Comment: @Phoshi - till then i will use ur first attempt

Answer (score 0):

You can cause Notepad to put the current date and time into the bottom of a file every time it is opened. Save ".LOG" in the top of the contents of the file. The resulting format is

```
hh:mm dd/mm/yyyy
```

Although probably not what you're after, it's an interesting trick that may be useful to someone coming from Google.

Comment: u can easily add through F5 in notepad